# Why is 'self' required to call a Ruby method from within its constructor?

Tags: ruby

If I have a class like this:

```
class Person

  def initialize(options={})
    self.name = options[:name]
  end

  def name=(name)
    @name = name
  end

end
```

... then the 'name=' method gets called and I get what I expect. But if I alter the example slightly to drop the 'self' from the call to 'name=' then the method is never called:

```
class Person

  def initialize(options={})
    name = options[:name]
  end

  def name=(name)
    @name = name
  end

end
```

Why is this? Why must 'self' be there? I was under the impression that the implicit 'self' would be set as expected in the 'initialize' constructor and therefor would behave as the first example.

Comment: BTW, self is required to call an accessor not just in the constructor but in every other instance method too

Comment: This is certainly *related* to the question it is marked a duplicate of, but by the time someone knows the question asked in the marked duplicate, this question is already answered.  This question is about the appearance of needing `self.` for all instance methods called in `initialize`.  The fact that `self.` is needed for accessors is the *answer* to this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ruby doesn't know if you want to make a local variable named "name" or use the member variable.

self.name tells it you want to use the member variable.

There isn't any syntax for saying you want to create a local variable, so that has to be the default.

(Also, member variables aren't real, but you know what I mean)

Comment: note that this is not only the case during initialization, but also during any instance method.

Comment: @xaxxon, the Ruby term for member variable would be `instance method`

Comment: @ThongKuah yeah, I hate that.  because they serve two different logical purposes.

Comment: @ThongKuah: Instance methods and instance variables are very different things.

Comment: @muistooshort yup, I'm however, referring to `self.name=` which is calling an instance method :)

Answer (score -1):

*Why is 'self' required to call a Ruby method from within its constructor?*

In general, it's not:

```
class Person
  def initialize(options={})
    set_name(options[:name]) # Calls `set_name` method; no `self.` required
  end

  def set_name(name)
    @name = name
  end
end
```

The need for `self.` in your code has nothing to do with being in the constructor: you can call any normal instance method from within `initialize` or elsewhere in the class without using `self.`.

What's going on is that you're trying to call a setter method (an instance method whose name ends with `=`, e.g. `name=`), which are handled as a special case in Ruby.

According to *The Ruby Programming Language*:

> The rule is that assignment expressions will only invoke a setter method when invoked through an object.  If you want to use a setter from within the class that defines it, invoke it explicitly through `self`.

So again, it's not that Ruby doesn't know what `self` refers to during execution of the constructor -- it does -- it's that in this case you're trying to call a setter, which requires invocation through an object.

In your code, `name = options[:name]` creates and sets a local variable called `name`.